# Use *ngFor index to group multiple iterations in one row

Tags: angular, ngfor

I've been trying to construct a dynamic input-dialog with multiple columns. Basicaly there's a list of fields and for every two fields I want to construct a row. My attempt looked like this (not even sure if this is possible)

```
<div *ngFor="let f of fields; let i = index">
    <div class="row" *ngIf="i % 2 = 1">
        <div *ngFor="let field of [fields[i],fields[i+1]]">
            <div class="col-3"><label>{{field.key}}</label></div>
            <div class="col-3"><input [(ngModel)]="object[field.key]"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

fields is a map of all the fields in object and looks like this:

```
[{key: fieldName,value: fieldValue},...]
```

clearly since I'm here my code isn't working, I'm open to suggestions for other implementations.

Comment: So you mean key,value from _2 objects_ in fields should be in a row?

Comment: yes if fields has a size of 10 I want 5 rows with 2 labels for the key's and 2 input fields to alter the values

Comment: What do you want to do when you have odd number of fields, for example 7?

Comment: Than I would like the first column to have the value the second column should remain empty (might indeed be a problem atm)

Comment: It would cause a problem because you will need to check if index is out of bounds (for `fields[i+1]`).

Comment: @ex0dm3nt thank I'll take that in consideration.

Comment: `*ngIf="i % 2 = 1"` ow...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simple way to do it is to precalculate rows array into additional property:

```javascript
this.itemsPerRow = 2
this.rows = Array.from(
  Array(Math.ceil(this.fields.length / this.itemsPerRow)).keys()
)
```

Then in HTML you would use two loops with slice pipe:

```html
<div *ngFor="let i of rows" class="row">
  <div *ngFor="let field of fields | slice:(i*itemsPerRow):(i+1)*itemsPerRow">
    <div class="col-3"><label>{{field.key}}</label></div>
    <div class="col-3"><input [(ngModel)]="object[field.key]"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/GVVyta1mqWAKP09V7Qvw?p=preview

Comment: This is a very clean solution!

Answer (score 1):

Try in this way:

```
<div *ngFor="let f of fields; let i = index">
    <div class="row" *ngIf="i % 2 === 1"> // === rather than =
        <div *ngFor="let field of [fields[i-1],fields[i]]"> // call previous element
            <div class="col-3"><label>{{field.key}}</label></div>
            <div class="col-3"><input [(ngModel)]="object[field.key]"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Firsty, you have to use equeal operator in *ngIf* condition
Additionaly, your child-HTML-code must depend on odd values to not called unexist positions in array (i - 1). Remember, that first index value is **0**

Comment: Good idea, though I think you need to compare modulo to zero (`i % 2 === 0`) and check for undefined values inside the inner for (`*ngIf="field"`).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line

```
<div *ngFor="let f of fields" let i = index>
```

to this

```
<div *ngFor="let f of fields; let i = index">
```

Comment: Sorry that was a typo I had it the way you suggested, I'll edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for input

```
<input [(ngModel)]="field.value" name="{{field.key}}" />
```

Your values are in value property

Comment: Don't know if somethign went wrong but nothing is shown

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve the columns with this html. Only having some trouble with CSS atm so it does not yet look the way it should but structurally It's correct now.

```
<div class="ui-grid ui-grid-responsive ui-fluid" *ngIf="saveObject">
    <div *ngFor="let f of fields; let i = index">
        <div *ngIf="i % 2 === 1 && i < fields?.length" class="ui-grid-row">
            <div *ngFor="let field of [fields[i-1],fields[i]]">
                <div class="ui-grid-col-3 field-label"><label for="attribute">{{field.key}}</label></div>
                <div class="ui-grid-col-3">
                    <p-checkbox *ngIf="booleanFields.indexOf(field.key) !== -1" binary="true" [(ngModel)]="saveObject[field.key]"></p-checkbox>
                    <p-calendar *ngIf="dateFields.indexOf(field.key) !== -1" [(ngModel)]="saveObject[field.key]" dateFormat="yy-mm-dd" [showIcon]="true"></p-calendar>
                    <input *ngIf="(booleanFields.indexOf(field.key) === -1) && (dateFields.indexOf(field.key) === -1)" pInputText id="attribute" [(ngModel)]="saveObject[field.key]"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="fields?.length % 2 === 1 && i === fields?.length - 1">
            <div *ngFor="let field of [fields[i]]">
                <div class="ui-grid-col-6 field-label"><label for="attributeEnd">{{field.key}}</label></div>
                <div class="ui-grid-col-6">
                    <p-checkbox *ngIf="booleanFields.indexOf(field.key) !== -1" binary="true" [(ngModel)]="saveObject[field.key]"></p-checkbox>
                    <p-calendar *ngIf="dateFields.indexOf(field.key) !== -1" [(ngModel)]="saveObject[field.key]" dateFormat="yy-mm-dd" [showIcon]="true"></p-calendar>
                    <input *ngIf="(booleanFields.indexOf(field.key) === -1) && (dateFields.indexOf(field.key) === -1)" pInputText id="attributeEnd" [(ngModel)]="saveObject[field.key]"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

ended up with a bit of duplicate code and there Might be beter solutions but I'll stick with this for now.
Big thanks to everyone who responded.

Answer (score 0):

Modified Jaroslaw's solution worked for me (3 items per row):

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let a of array; let i = index">
    <div class="row" *ngIf="i % 3 === 0">
        <div *ngFor="let item of [array[i],array[i+1],array[i+2]]" class="col-md-4">
            <ng-container *ngIf="item">
```