# Showing data with index value in grid view

Tags: android, html, ionic-framework, gridview, ionic3

Here is my code :

```
<ion-grid no-padding>
    <ion-row *ngFor="let item of items"  let i=index no-padding>
      <ion-col col-6 col-sm-3 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3>
        <ion-card [ngStyle]="{'background': 'url(' + item.PImage + ')'}"> 
          <div *ngIf="item.Ptype == 'cash'" class="cash-cat-icon"></div>
          <div *ngIf="item.Ptype == 'cheque'" class="cheque-cat-icon"></div>   
          <div>
          <h2 item-title >{{item.pName}}</h2>
          <h4 item-title >RS: {{item.PPrice}}</h4>
          </div>
        </ion-card>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col col-6 col-sm-3 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3>
          <ion-card [ngStyle]="{'background': 'url(' + item.PImage + ')'}"> 
            <div *ngIf="item.Ptype == 'cash'" class="cash-cat-icon"></div>
            <div *ngIf="item.Ptype == 'cheque'" class="cheque-cat-icon"></div>   
            <div>
            <h2 item-title >{{item.pName}}</h2>
            <h4 item-title >RS: {{item.PPrice}}</h4>
            </div>
          </ion-card>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
```

Now my data is like : { name1, name2, name3, name4, name5, name6 }

But in my screen I am getting like :

```
name1  name1
name2 name2
name3 name3
name4 name4
```

But i want like :

```
name1 name2
name3 name4
name5 name6
```

Please help me out.How can I achieve this! I know to keep index but don't know how to show that values in the respective grid

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use \*ngFor index to group multiple iterations in one row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42853886/use-ngfor-index-to-group-multiple-iterations-in-one-row)

Comment: also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41597438/how-to-display-two-table-columns-per-row-in-angular-2-loop-angular2-equivalent

Comment: @SurajRao   i tried those link, din work.So only have posted here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the ion-col in ng-container and give condition to enter only for even index

```
 <ion-grid no-padding>
    <ion-row  no-padding *ngFor="let item of items;let i=index">
      <ng-container *ngIf="i % 2 == 0">
      <ion-col col-6 col-sm-3 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 *ngIf="i < items.length">
        <ion-card [ngStyle]="{'background': 'url(' + items[i].PImage + ')'}"> 
          <div *ngIf="items[i].Ptype == 'cash'" class="cash-cat-icon"></div>
          <div *ngIf="items[i].Ptype == 'cheque'" class="cheque-cat-icon"></div>   
          <div>
          <h2 item-title >{{items[i].pName}}</h2>
          <h4 item-title >RS: {{items[i].PPrice}}</h4>
          </div>
        </ion-card>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col col-6 col-sm-3 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 *ngIf="i + 1 < items.length">
       <ion-card [ngStyle]="{'background': 'url(' + items[i+1].PImage + ')'}"> 
          <div *ngIf="items[i+1].Ptype == 'cash'" class="cash-cat-icon"></div>
          <div *ngIf="items[i+1].Ptype == 'cheque'" class="cheque-cat-icon"></div>   
          <div>
          <h2 item-title >{{items[i+1].pName}}</h2>
          <h4 item-title >RS: {{items[i+1].PPrice}}</h4>
          </div>
        </ion-card>
      </ion-col>
      </ng-container>
</ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

pls check the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-ndgdrw?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)

Comment: dont think this is what OP is looking for.. They want two column items per row as far as I can see

Comment: @Abinesh Joyel i am not getting this.i want two column per row .please check my question

Comment: If they wants two column in one row it will duplicate only. I confused now what they are looking for

Comment: @david sorry if i mistaken. i will change my answer

Comment: @AbineshJoyel   i want two column per row. If my data is like 1,2,3,4,5,6.then i want [ 1,2 ] , next row [3,4] like that

Comment: @david i will update it you can achieve it by index of ngFor loop

Comment: @AbineshJoyel yes, that will be helpfull

Comment: @AbineshJoyel  ia m getting this error :`TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null`

Comment: @david can you check the demo and also items should be of array

Comment: @AbineshJoyel  mine is like this `[{"Pd":"1","Pname”:”#110318-00001-001”},{"Pd”:”2”,”Pname”:”#110318-00001-001”},{"Pd”:”3”,”Pname”:”#110318-00001-001"}]
`

Comment: pls check with this https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-ndgdrw?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html

Comment: @AbineshJoyel  sorry for the late replay.Yeah its fine now.But one issue was here `<div *ngIf="items[i].Ptype == 'cash'" class="cash-cat-icon"></div>
          <div *ngIf="items[i].Ptype == 'cheque'" class="cheque-cat-icon"></div> ` i have only one cheque. that is my second cell grid.But in that particular cell i can see both dots which represent both checque and cash

Comment: @AbineshJoyel why its showing like that.Any idea  ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168441/discussion-between-abinesh-joyel-and-david).

Comment: @AbineshJoyel  can u please help me here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49817228/on-click-function-not-showing-the-exact-data

Comment: @david i will check it and reply