# On click function not showing the exact data

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, gridview, ionic3

I have one row with two columns as grid view to populate the date from the sevrver. By view everything is fine. But say i have 2 row with 4 column.like below :

```
a   b
c   d
```

So i have a click function on my row where selected item can see as detail view page.But the issues here is .For example if i select first grid cell in first row. that is ‘A’.Then in detail page its showing all the details about ‘A’

Same if i select ‘B’ then also in detail screen its showing as ‘A’ grid cell data only.Which is showing all the data about ‘A’.

**Things i tried :**

print the function of on click .if i select “A” then A is showing.If i select “B” then also on selected click function “A” Data only showing.

Here is my code :

```
<ion-grid no-padding>
      <ion-row no-padding *ngFor="let item of Data;let i=index" (click)="showDetails(item)">
      <ng-container *ngIf="i % 2 == 0">
        <ion-col col-6 col-sm-3 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 *ngIf="i < Data.length">
            <ion-card no-margin>          
              <div gallery-title>
              <h2 item-title text-wrap text-center>{{Data[i].ProductName}}</h2>
              </div>
            </ion-card>
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col col-6 col-sm-3 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 *ngIf="i+1  < Data.length">
            <ion-card no-margin>         
            <div gallery-title>
              <h2 item-title text-wrap text-center>{{Data[i+1].ProductName}}</h2>
              </div>
            </ion-card>
          </ion-col>
      </ng-container>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
```

Any help.I don't know what i am doing wrong here.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: I think you forgot to fill the blank here for the issue "But the issues here is .". We hardly know what you are trying to achieve

Comment: if i click "A" then its moving to detail page and showing the data of "A".Same row if i click  "B" CELL that time also its showing the "A" data only...not showing the "B" data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its simple put the click in ion-col and that's it what you need is to pass the Data array with index in showDetails function

```
<ion-grid no-padding>
      <ion-row no-padding *ngFor="let item of Data;let i=index" (click)="showDetails(item)">
      <ng-container *ngIf="i % 2 == 0">
        <ion-col col-6 col-sm-3 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 *ngIf="i < Data.length" (click)="showDetails(Data[i])">
            <ion-card no-margin>          
              <div gallery-title>
              <h2 item-title text-wrap text-center>{{Data[i].ProductName}}</h2>
              </div>
            </ion-card>
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col col-6 col-sm-3 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 *ngIf="i+1  < Data.length" (click)="showDetails(Data[i+1])">
            <ion-card no-margin>         
            <div gallery-title>
              <h2 item-title text-wrap text-center>{{Data[i+1].ProductName}}</h2>
              </div>
            </ion-card>
          </ion-col>
      </ng-container>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
```

Comment: any help here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49864633/ionic-3-cordova-build-android-is-not-working

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this right, it looks as though you're iterating over Data four times, but only actually outputting two rows from it (your `*ngIf="i % 2 == 0"` is causing you to lose access to two of your `item`s.

So you're outputting the column for B on the first pass, in which case item is actually still item A.

Because of the way the Ionic columns work, you probably don't need to write it like this. Try the following:

```
<ion-grid no-padding>
  <ion-row no-padding>
    <ion-col col-6 col-sm-3 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 *ngFor="let item of Data" (click)="showDetails(item)">
        <ion-card no-margin>          
          <div gallery-title>
            <h2 item-title text-wrap text-center>{{ item.ProductName }}</h2>
          </div>
        </ion-card>
      </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

You're only going to have one row with this, but the columns *should* work out the way you want.

Comment: but how the grid view will come.ur code is coming at right side only. Not like grid view like one row with two column

Comment: @david it's the exact same code as you : you create a row, and add two columns in it.  You were just adding some logic that you thought was required, but it isn't.

Comment: Because of the way you're defining your columns, they should get laid out in the way you want. They'll just all technically be inside of a single row. If you really want two rows (which, to be fair, would be semantically correct) we can have a rethink about my solution.

Comment: @lordchancellor  i understand ur logic, but same way code in my post only i can achive with two column with single row. With ur i tried to make an 2 column with single row. But not able to achive that

Comment: @lordchancellor can u help me to achieve 2 col per row.As per i explained n my post.

Answer (score 0):

The click event you have bound is on the row not the column. I would suggest moving the click event to the `<ion-col` elements instead.